# Perl Compiling PP issue in Strawberry Perl

Tags: perl, compiler-errors, strawberry-perl, perl-packager, mojo-dom

I am having issues with compiling in Windows (Strawberry Perl v5.32.0) a script that references a custom module.  My Perl skills could be rated as a 3/10 with 10 being the best and have researched this problem to the best of my ability.

When I run this, it runs fine and gives expected results:

pp -M PAR -M Mojolicious  -C -a  "C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib\Mojo\resources\html_entities.txt;Mojo\resources\html_entities.txt" ^  -x -o testCorpProg.exe  C:\Strawberry\Custom\new_corp_filing.pl

When I run the executable built, it gives me this:

*Unable to open html entities file (C:\Users\perluser\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73636861707061\temp-10308\inc\lib\Mojo\resources\html_entities.txt): No such file or directory at C:\Users\perluser\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73636861707061\temp-10308\inc\lib/Mojo/Base.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\perluser\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73636861707061\temp-10308\inc\lib/Mojo/Base.pm line 14.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\perluser\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73636861707061\temp-10308\inc\lib/Mojo/DOM.pm line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\perluser\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73636861707061\temp-10308\inc\lib/Mojo/DOM.pm line 2.
Compilation failed in require at C:\Users\perluser\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73636861707061\temp-10308\inc\lib/SubmitCorpFiling.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at C:\Users\perluser\AppData\Local\Temp\par-73636861707061\temp-10308\inc\lib/SubmitCorpFiling.pm line 11.
Compilation failed in require at script/new_corp_filing.pl line 3.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script/new_corp_filing.pl line 3.*

The top of my custom module looks like this:

```
package SubmitCorpFiling;

use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;

use Text::CSV_XS;
use Carp qw(carp croak cluck);
use File::Basename;
use URI::Query;
use Mojo::DOM;
use List::MoreUtils qw(any all firstval);
use Business::CreditCard qw(validate_card);
use JSON::PP qw(decode_json);
use Locale::SubCountry;
```

I have checked the PM install of Mojolicious and have the latest version installed (9.19).  I am pretty sure the issue lay within that module (or **Mojo::DOM**).

```
cpan> install Mojolicious
Mojolicious is up to date (9.19).
```

I have my Windows environment **PERL5LIB**=C:\Strawberry\Custom\lib; C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib; C:\Strawberry\perl\lib

Is there anyone who has experienced this issue and if so resolved it?  Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  After traversing through the original post, I was able to see that Module::ScanDeps in CPAM was not up to date (v1.31).  In github it was recently modified and now v1.32.  Pulling that PM out of github solved the problem.  Thanks!!!!